# To search index of both the cases of first letter of a string in R?

Tags: r, case-insensitive

I want to check the index of first letter in a string say `string1 = AAGA` and `string2= don`.For `string1` I use below code to get the index of upper-case letter.

```
string1 <- "AAGA"
fc <- substr(string1,1,1)
which(LETTERS==fc)
```

and for `string2` as in lower-case I use

```
string2 <- "don"
fc <- substr(string2,1,1)
which(letters==fc)
```

Either of the above codes works for one case. Now I want to check for both where I don't know the case of sting. I tried the below code, but i think it does not make any sense.

```
string2 <- "don"
fc <- substr(string2,1,1)
which(LETTERS==fc || letters==fc)
```

It works for none of the cases and returns `integer(0)` .How to do it for both the cases. Thanks

Comment: `which(c(LETTERS,letters)==fc)` works. You need to have 26*2 elements in the vector you're checking. Anything above 26 is lower-case.

Comment: You could choose ahead either to use `LETTERS` or `letters` and wrap `fc` in `toupper` or `tolower` respectively.

Comment: For whatever reason, there is also another function for this: `match(fc,c(LETTERS,letters))`

Comment: @Frank, why  `string1 <- "don" `;  `fc <- substr(string1,1,1); `
 `which(c(LETTERS,letters)==fc) return 30`

Comment: It should return 4 for `don`

Comment: @AwaitedOne : Expanding Frank's comment, you could get the right index using `(which(c(LETTERS, letters) == fc) - 1) %% 26 + 1` i.e. recycle 1:26 twice.

Comment: Ah, i thought you cared about whether it was upper or lower case. Alexis' first comment is spot on for what you're seeking: `first_char <- function(s) match(tolower(substr(s,1,1)),letters)`. Then you can do `first_char(string1)` etc.